# Why isn't a property in my ViewModel updated when DataGrid changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dictionary, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to create a UserControl, that will let me edit a Dictionary of type `Dictionary<string,string>` in a grid (just editing entries so far, not adding or deleting).

Whenever I bind the DataGrid to a Dictionary it shows the grid as read only, so I decieded to create a value converter, that would convert it to an `ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>` where `DictionaryEntry` is just a class with two properties `Key`, and `Value`.

This works for display the dictionary in the grid, but now when I make changes to the grid, my dictionary is not being updated.  I'm unsure why.

I think it's either a problem with the way I have my bindings set up, or my value converter.  If anyone could shed some light, that would be fantastic.

Below is the smallest demo I could make that shows what I'm doing.  Again the problem is when I change values in the grid, the `MyDictionary` on my `MainViewModel` is not updated..ever.  Why?

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"Key1", "Value1"},
                {"Key2", "Value2"},
                {"Key3", "Value3"}
            };
    }
    private Dictionary<string, string> _myDictionary;
    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return _myDictionary;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_myDictionary == value)
                return;
            _myDictionary = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyDictionary");
        }
    }
...
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"></local:MainViewModel>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Name="MainStackPanel" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}">
        <local:DictionaryGrid />
        <Button Content="Print Dictionary" Click="PrintDictionary"></Button>        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**DictionaryGrid.xaml**

```
<UserControl ...>
      <UserControl.Resources>
         <testingGrid:DictionaryToOcConverter x:Key="Converter" />
     </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDictionary, 
                                  Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" 
         />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**DictionaryToOcConverter.cs**

```
public class DictionaryToOcConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>();
        var dictionary = value as Dictionary<string, string>;
        if (dictionary != null)
        {
            foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
                collection.Add(new DictionaryEntry { Key = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value });
        }
        return collection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var entries = value as ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>;
        if (entries != null)
        {
            foreach (var entry in entries)
                dictionary.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }

        return dictionary;
    }
    public class DictionaryEntry
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's actually two issues here:  your `DictionaryEntry` class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged to work correctly with the binding engine, and secondarily it should implement IEditableObject because you want to edit items in a data grid and avoid 'random results'.  So your class should look something like this...

```
public class DictionaryEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject
{
    private string _k;
    [Description("The key")]
    public string K
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _k; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _k)
            {
                _k = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("K");
            }
        }
    }
    private string _v;
    [Description("The value")]
    public string V
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _v; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _v)
            {
                _v = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("V");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
    #region IEditableObject
    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
    public void CancelEdit()
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
    public void EndEdit()
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In your ViewModel (or code behind) you would instantiate it like this...

```
    public ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry> MyItems { get; set; } 
    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<DictionaryEntry>();
        MyItems.Add(new DictionaryEntry{K="string1", V="value1"});
        MyItems.Add(new DictionaryEntry { K = "color", V = "red" });
    }
```

...which is pretty close to what you have.  And the Xaml would look like this...

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    </DataGrid>
```

Those things will bring about the behaviour you are after.  I.e., edits will be sticky.

On the `IEditableObject` interface vis-à-vis DataGrids, it's a known 'gotcha' and there's a description of it here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx

which says...

> If you are not familiar with IEditableObject, see this MSDN article
>   which has a good explanation and code sample.  The DataGrid has baked
>   in functionality for transactional editing via the IEditableObject
>   interface.  When you begin editing a cell, the DataGrid gets into cell
>   editing mode as well as row editing mode.  What this means is that you
>   can cancel/commit cells as well as cancel/commit rows.  For example, I
>   edit cell 0 and press tab to the next cell.  Cell 0 is committed when
>   pressing tab.  I start typing in cell 1 and realize I want to cancel
>   the operation.  I press ‘Esc’ which reverts cell 1.  I now realize I
>   want to cancel the whole operation so I press ‘Esc’ again and now cell
>   0 is reverted back to its original value.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I made these changes.  The inner dictionary changes stick, but they are not coming back to my main view model, am I missing something that I have to do to get it to go back through IValueConverter?  The ConvertBack Method is never called, and not sure the correct way to invoke it, should it be called when the observable collection changes or do I have to wire something else up?

Comment: I didn't want to include it in my answer, but the value converter is pretty much a red herring.  I would bin it.  If the changes are working (which they should!), and you want notifications in a further layer of abstraction, then the VM should subscribe to each DictionaryEntry's property changed and implement a single event handler to process them.  Or just use the 'inner dictionary' as the VM's item source.